# What sql statement will give me this result?

Tags: sql-server

I do not know how to word my question properly. My apologies for that. I have a table like this:

```
EventId | Item | Type
--------+------+------
  1     | 123  |  A
  2     | 123  |  B
  3     | 123  |  C
  4     | 456  |  A
  5     | 456  |  B
```

I want to select only those items that do not have event of type C. Then only show event of type B of those items. So, the result should look like this:

```
EventId | Item | Type
--------+------+-------
   5    | 456  |  B
```

Comment: select * from (select * from table where type <> 'C') where type = 'B'

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick...

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Event', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #Event;

CREATE TABLE #Event (
    EventId INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Item INT NOT NULL,
    ItemType CHAR(1) NOT NULL 
    );
INSERT #Event (EventId, Item, ItemType) VALUES
    (1, 123, 'A'),
    (2, 123, 'B'),
    (3, 123, 'C'),
    (4, 456, 'A'),
    (5, 456, 'B');

--=======================================

SELECT 
    e1.EventId, e1.Item, e1.ItemType
FROM
    #Event e1
WHERE
    e1.ItemType = 'B'
    AND NOT EXISTS (
                    SELECT 1
                    FROM #Event e2
                    WHERE 
                        e1.Item = e2.Item
                        AND e2.ItemType = 'C'
                    );
```

Results...

```
EventId     Item        ItemType
----------- ----------- --------
5           456         B
```

Answer (score 0):

You answer based on said constrain

```
SELECT 
    e1.EventId, e1.Item, e1.ItemType
FROM
    Event e1
INNER JOIN Event e2 ON e1.Item != e2.Item
WHERE   e1.ItemType = 'B'
    AND e2.ItemType = 'C'
```

Output:

[image]

**Note**: Inner `SELECT` query may cause the performance issue while processing large number of records comparing to `INNER JOIN`